# ¿Cómo descargar archivo de excel adjunto php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Trato de descargar un archivo de *excel* que tengo en una carpeta local
y también lo guarde en *mysql*.

Aquí el código, que se supone que en adjunto es el archivo que muestra en *mysql* y en descarga es donde lo debería descargar

```
 <?php 
    include("configuracion.php");
    
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];//le asigno una variable 
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM ordenes WHERE id =".$id; 
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query1)){ 
    while($usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $asunto = $usuario['asunto']; 
    $detail = $usuario['detail'];
    $adicional = $usuario['adicional'];
    $que = $usuario['que'];
    $firma = $usuario['firma'];
    $estatus = $usuario['estatus'];
    $que = $usuario['que'];
    $updated_at = $usuario['updated_at'];
    $created_at = $usuario['created_at'];
    $fecha_resolucion = $usuario['fecha_resolucion'];
    $adjunto = $usuario['adjunto'];
   }
    }
    }
  ?>
    <script>
    function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
    }
    </script>
    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
    <div class="pull-left">
    <h2> Ver Requerimiento de trabajo</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
    <button onclick="goBack()"class="btn btn-primary">Atras</button>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <strong>Asunto:</strong>
    <?php if(isset($asunto)) echo $asunto; ?>            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <strong>Detalles:</strong>
    <?php if(isset($detail)) echo $detail; ?>            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <strong>
    
    Hora Cerrada o Actualizada:</strong>
    <?php if(isset($updated_at)) echo $updated_at; ?>            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <strong>Comentarios :</strong>
    <?php if(isset($adicional)) echo $adicional; ?>            </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <strong>Status :</strong>
    <?php if(isset($estatus)) echo $estatus; ?>            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <strong>¿Que se realizo?:</strong>
    <?php if(isset($que)) echo $que; ?>            </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <strong>Firmado por:</strong>
    <?php if(isset($firma)) echo $firma; ?>            </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <strong>Fecha Estimada de Resolucion :</strong>
    <?php if(isset($fecha_resolucion)) echo $fecha_resolucion; ?>            </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <strong>Excel :</strong>
    
    <?php
    if(isset($adjunto)) echo $adjunto; 
    
    
    
    ?>  
    <a href="archivos?id=<?php echo $usuario['id'] ?>"download>download</a> 
    
    
    
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <strong>Se Creo a las :</strong>
    <?php if(isset($created_at)) echo $created_at; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <strong>¿Se cambio a Incidencia?:</strong>
    <?php if(isset($inc)) echo $inc; ?>            </div>
    </div>
```

Para que se descargue el archivo que le estoy mandando al *excel* desde la carpeta con el botón.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "no me lo descarga bien"?¿Que problema genera?¿Que has intentado?

Comment: Si solo necesitas la descarga directa, simplemente crea un enlace `echo "<a href=\"ruta/$adjunto\">$adjunto</a>";` y asegúrate de establecer la ruta correcta.

Comment: que tal solo el boton me descargar un formato html mas no me descarga el archivo que esta en la carpeta archivos de la pagina web que estoy desarrollando

Comment: ya pero me marca acceso prohibido

Comment: ya quedo gracias lo puedes poner como respuesta para valorarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo hay que crear el enlace especificando la ruta adecuada:

```
<?php
if(isset($adjunto)) {
   echo "<a href=\"carpeta-donde-tienes-el-archivo/$adjunto\">$adjunto</a>";
}
?>
```

No es necesario que hagas un *script* para descarga, el navegador se encargará de enviar los encabezados adecuados y ventana de opciones por tratarse de un archivo no interpretable directamente en web: (html, imagen, javascript, texto, etc.)